# current row + previous row in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like

```
beginv  nm  nm1 qty qty1    endinv  seq
0        a  ab1 5   7          0    1
0        a  ab2 15  7          0    2
0        a  ab3 11  9          0    3
0        a  ab3 11  9          0    4
0        a  ab3 11  9          0    5
0        b  ab2 10  14         0    1
0        b  ab3 11  9          0    2
0        c  ab1 11  9          0    1
0        c  ab2 15  9          0    2
0        c  ab3 15  9          0    3
```

Is there a way to show like below

```
beginv  nm  nm1 qty qty1    endinv  seq
0        a  ab1 5   7          7    1
0        a  ab2 15  7          15   2
0        a  ab3 11  9          17   3
0        a  ab3 11  9          17   4
0        a  ab3 11  9          17   5
0        b  ab2 10  14         14   1
0        b  ab3 11  9          16   2
0        c  ab1 11  9          9    1
0        c  ab2 15  9          15   2
0        c  ab3 15  9          21   3
```

if seq is 1 then endinv=qty1 else (previous)endinv+(qty-qty1)
and same nm,nm1 is repeating then previous endiv (e.g. "a" with "ab3" repeats three times with same endinv value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can do this with a couple of windowed conditional `SUM`s. Note, however, the results do *not* match that in your expected results, but I am assuming that that is because your expected results are wrong. You state the required logic is *"(previous)endinv+(qty-qty1)"*, however, when `seq` has a value of `4` and `nm` a value of `a`, the value of `endinv` in `17`. Applying your logic, however, you have `17 + 11 - 9` which equals `19` **not** `17`.

```sql
SELECT beginv,
       nm,
       nm1,
       qty,
       qty1,
       SUM(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN qty1 ELSE qty END) OVER (PARTITION BY nm ORDER BY seq ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) -
       SUM(CASE seq WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE qty1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY nm ORDER BY seq ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS endinv,
       seq
FROM (VALUES(0,'a','ab1',5 ,7 ,0,1),
            (0,'a','ab2',15,7 ,0,2),
            (0,'a','ab3',11,9 ,0,3),
            (0,'a','ab3',11,9 ,0,4),
            (0,'a','ab3',11,9 ,0,5),
            (0,'b','ab2',10,14,0,1),
            (0,'b','ab3',11,9 ,0,2),
            (0,'c','ab1',11,9 ,0,1),
            (0,'c','ab2',15,9 ,0,2),
            (0,'c','ab3',15,9 ,0,3))V(beginv,nm,nm1,qty,qty1,endinv,seq);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=220fd5dcd63ce19f9363a4050c8f9126)

Comment: actually that is one condition if same nm with nm1 comes again then endinv value shoulde be same as previous  (e.g. "a" with "ab3" repeats three times with same endinv value)

Comment: I don't understand your comment there, @deeSQL , but it sounds like you're moving the goalposts... Something that is really frowned on *after* you've received answers.

Comment: actualy thats what i mean in my post " same nm,nm1 is repeating then previous endiv (e.g. "a" with "ab3" repeats three times with same endinv value)" but not able to elaborate properly i guess. he he he. Apology for that